# Possible to add condition to Required field so my default value in my drop down list for is considered invalid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a DropDownListFor with a default value of "Select Priority". I'm trying to make this drop down required, but since it recognizes the default value as being valid it will never trigger as being invalid. How can I customize the Required field in my ViewModel to trigger invalid when the value is still at the default value of "Select Priority"?

ViewModel:
[Required(ErrorMessage="Choose a Priority")]
public string Priority { get; set; }

View:
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Priority, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})

Is there some way to say, If the Priority value is set to "Select Priority" then make the ModelState invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do when using your DropDownListFor:

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(new SelectListItem{ Text="Choose a Priority", Value = "0" , Disabled = true, Selected = true}, /*rest of your data*/);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Although this would work, I'm populating the list from a database, in which the first value is the "Select Priority" so adding another SelectListItem would create another default value and look bad. I'm looking for something more on the side of editing the ViewModel.

Comment: @Afdufsko. Can you redesign the database to remove the first value. I would prefer this option as that makes the most sense. If you can't i am guessing you would have to check the model to see if the value posted is the ID of the first value. That way you can then add something to ModelState.AddModelError and then return the view. Don't forget to repopulate the DropdownList.